# Change rand_r to srand/rand

Tags: c++

I would like to change use of **rand_r** method for **srand/rand** or with other random generator with seed.

In code there is a loop that call a **train** method with seed.

```
int nseeds = 5;
for (int seed = 0; seed < nseeds; seed ++)
{
    c.train(K, reps, gradientReps, improveReps, lambda, seed, SYMMETRICDIFF);
}
```

In **train** method there are 3 calls for **rand_r** that I would like to change. I thought that I could call **srand** at the beginning with given seed and then simply call for **rand()** method, but I don't know if this is a proper way. What do you think?

```
void Cluster::train(int K, int reps, int gradientReps, int improveReps, Scalar lambda, int seed, int whichLoss)
{
  unsigned int seed_ = seed;
  unsigned int* sptr = &seed_;
  //srand(seed);

  for (int rep = 0; rep < reps; rep ++)
  {
    for (int k = 0; k < K; k ++)
      if (rep == 0 or (int) chat[k].size() == 0 or (int) chat[k].size() == gd->nNodes)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < gd->nNodes; i ++)
          if (rand_r(sptr) % 2 == 0) chat[k].insert(i);
        for (int i = 0; i < gd->nEdgeFeatures; i ++)
          theta[k*gd->nEdgeFeatures + i] = 0;

        theta[k*gd->nEdgeFeatures + rand_r(sptr)%gd->nEdgeFeatures] = 1.0;
      }

    for (int k = 0; k < K; k ++)
    {
      for (int o = 0; o < K; o ++)
      {
        int x1 = o;
        int x2 = rand_r(sptr) % K;
        // code
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Link for [source](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~jmcauley/code/code_nips2012.tar.gz). The above code is in main.cpp and cluster.cpp.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to give a seed at each loop. In general, you only have to set the seed ONCE, when you start your program.

Comment: I think code uses different seeds for each loop.

Comment: When you set the same seed at each run, it is NOT random ! Then I don't understand what you want to do. The only reason I know to set the seed in a loop is for reproductibility in multi-threaded architecture. It doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: The same? I think there the seed is being increment each loop.

Comment: @Caduchon Sometimes reproducibility is desired in other applications too. Looks like machine learning or something, so it's OK.

Comment: If you choose the same seed for each run, your program will run with exactly the same values. This is not random.

Comment: @matb: this is not reproductibility. For reproductibility, you just have to set the seed when your program starts.

Comment: @mardok The basic idea seems more or less correct. You should look what rand_r really does and see if rand() will be a good replacement. The source you posted suggests that rand_r changes seed each time it is called. Hard to be certain without looking at the full source code.

Comment: @Caduchon Let's say you have three independent tests in your program, each one must be deterministic. With one seed rearranging them changes the result, with one srand per test everything is OK. Plus, different parts of the program may need different seeds (and therefore srand/rand is actually a bad idea and new C++ standard has a better solution **discouraging** one seed per program).

Comment: @matb: writing like that, you cann't run your independant tests in parallel threads...

Comment: If you have multiple threads, you need to set the seed independently for each thread if you want reproducible results. If you set the seed once at the beginning, it will definitely not be reproducible in a multi-threaded environment. Anyway, this is just one function shown here and you cannot say where the seed should be set if you don't know more about the structure of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++11, I would use the [new random number library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). If not, you should try [Boost random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) (it's basically the same). I recommend using the `mt19937` random number engine, it produces pretty good quality random numbers, and it's also fast.

Then your code will look like this:

```
std::mt19937 rng;
...
std::uniform_int_distribution dist(0, K - 1);
...
int x2 = dist(rng);
```